# Unable to use WifiNetworkSpecifier in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried to use following code snippet in my XAMARIN project using **Visual Studio** (Windows 10, Android platform API 29).

**WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();**

But looks like "WifiNetworkSpecifier" is not available for Visual Studio.

`Error: CS0246 The type or namespace name 'WifiNetworkSpecifier' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Please share workaround to resolve this issue.

VERSION DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.6.2
- Xamarin.Android SDK   10.3.1.4 (d16-6/3a10de9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, right click `Android project` => `Property` => `Application` and choose the `Target Framework` to `Android 10.0(Q)` or `higher`:

[image]

Then in your project, reference the namespace:

```
using Android.Net.Wifi;
```

Then you can use [WifiNetworkSpecifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier) in your project:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{

        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the namespace

```
using Android.Net.Wifi;
```

is VS, right clicking on the line that has the error should offer you a prompt to automatically suggest potential fixes